# YAJL internal error: attempted use of non-string object as key

Tags: chef-infra

I am currently receiving this error during first-boot chef. The error occurs right before the chef finishes by displaying a success message. The recipes have been working previously, and I ave not made any changes to them.

So my question is, how do I fix this error?

Comment: Something is ending up in your node data that isn't valid JSON. Check the file you are passing in via -j

Comment: Please add a [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What command did you run? What error do you see? Stacktraces?

Comment: What version of Chef as well?  Might be an ffi-yajl bug introduced in 11.14.0 but its impossible to tell from your question.

Answer (score 0):

I found myself with two directories each with a different rvm gemset.  Chef (a knife node delete command) worked in one but returned an error in the other:

ffi-yajl/json_gem is deprecated, these monkeypatches will be dropped shortly

Although this does not sound like a fatal error to me, knife commands failed with that message.

It turns out that if I ...

 `gem install ffi-yajl -v 1.2
 gem unistall ffi-yajl -v 1.3.1`

... my problems vanished and knife now works correctly.

YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

Also a separate solution for chef bootstrap failing with the same error (as the post below!).

ffi-yajl/json_gem is deprecated, these monkeypatches will be dropped shortly

I inserted a 'gem install json' command immediately before the 'gem install chef' command in the (amazon.erb) bootstrap template.